# Lovasz local lemma and chernoff bound

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random, coloring, probabilistic-method

I am really stuck when it comes to solving the problem below.
I think I should use Lovasz's local lemma symmetric version but I don't really know how?
I don't know how to find the probability of the occurrence of bad events. I appreciate your help in advance.[image]

Comment: What have you tried: how are you using randomness, what do you think the bad events should be, what are the dependencies between them, why is it hard to find the probability, and how far have you gotten with that?